# Extract first element of an int object with multiple rows

Tags: python

I have an object `x`

```
print(x)
1
1
2

print(type(x).__name__)
int
int
int
```

How do I extract only the first `1` from it. If I try `x[0]`, I get the following message

> `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

I found a lot of questions about the error but none of the solutions worked for me.

---

Here is the `stdin` from where `x` was read

```
3
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
```

Here is how it was read

```
q = int(input().strip())
for a0 in range(q):
    x,y,z = input().strip().split(' ')
    x,y,z = [int(x),int(y),int(z)]
```

Comment: Can you show what `x` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you store them in a container (for example a `list`) during the loop in case you want to access them later on.

For example:

```
q = int(input().strip())
res = []
for a0 in range(q):
    x,y,z = input().strip().split(' ')
    res.append([int(x),int(y),int(z)])
print(res)   # all x, y and z
```

or to access specific elements:

```
print(res[0][0])   # first x
print(res[1][0])   # second x
print(res[0][1])   # first y
```